# Time series database

Tags: python, database

several times per day I need to store real time series of data with 0.5s time resolution and max. 1 hour in length. The data are numbers, or array of numbers. The data logging can run simultaneously for several series at one time. There can be tens or max. hundreds of series stored per 1 day. The data will be stored on local PC running the logging application. The application will be written in Python.

In Python I will then plot graphs and compute some analytics from the data.

Can you recommend suitable database for my case?

Comment: I wondered if you could share what solution you end up using because I have the same situation.

Answer (score -1):

I'd start with [SQLite3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html).

It requires very little configuration and is suitable for many purposes.

If you reach the point where you have *a lot* of data, you might consider switching to PostgreSQL.

This is a tough question to answer well without knowing many more specifics about the scenario. However, the great thing about databases is that it is often possible to switch which database you are using with only minor modifications to the front-end code, which is another reason to start with something relatively simple and light-weight.

Comment: Is it wise to store all the data into single table or create separate table for each logging session? Consider there can be 50 000 samples to be stored per one day and I need history of at least 60 days.

Comment: 3 million rows is not too huge of a table, especially if you set up your indexes properly. Since all the data "looks" the same, having it in the same table is sensible.

Answer (score -1):

Look at [redis for timeseries](https://github.com/antirez/redis-timeseries), it is very simple storage which gives you better performance, in comparison with sql solutions.